# Recover password in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, password-recovery

Is it possible to recover the password for an email account in [Outlook 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook#Outlook_2010)? I need to re-install Outlook, and I don't know the password of the mailbox.

Alternatively, is it possible to just move the `.pst` file? Is the username and password stored within that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a network sniffing tool like [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on your machine. Next, start a trace and have Outlook check your e-mail. Finally, closely examine the generated traces. Somewhere in there is your password that is being sent as plain text.

Comment: Hah that did the trick. Thansk!